# Error accessing ThreadStart object inside a function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck up at a peculiar issue and want some help in resolving this.

I have the following code below

```
    public partial class FrmSoftJobProcess : Form
        {
            private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;
            public FrmSoftJobProcess()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Load += FrmJobProcess_Load;
                FormClosing += FrmJobProcess_FormClosing;
                if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
                {
                    InitializeInstanceFields();
                    InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
                }

            }
            private void InitializeInstanceFields()
            {
                PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensProfileThreadFunction);
                PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate);
                PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensPlanThreadFunction);
                PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);
            }
            private ThreadStart PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate;
            private Thread PlotLensProfileThread;
            private ThreadStart PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate;
            private Thread PlotLensPlanThread;
-------------------
-----------------------
}
```

The class above has the following function

```
 private   void PlotLensProfileThreadFunction()
        {
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag =FrontEndStructures. InitErrorFlag();
            Graphics InMedia = this.PicLensPlot.CreateGraphics();

           PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread(); // how can I access this? I cant create object as its a field. 
           // var PlotRef = PlotLensProfileThread;
            try
            {
                PlotRef.ThreadInGrphRef = InMedia;
                PlotRef.ThreadInConcavePaths = ConcavePaths;
                PlotRef.ThreadInConvexPaths = ConvexPaths;
                PlotRef.ThreadPlotOptions = PlotOptions.ProfileView;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepSixData = JobData.StepSixData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepFiveData = JobData.StepFiveData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepFourData = JobData.StepFourData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepThreeData = JobData.StepThreeData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepTwoData = JobData.StepTwoData;
                PlotRef.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag;
                PlotRef.MeridianConcave = MeridianConcave;
                PlotRef.MeridianEdge = MeridianEdge;
                PlotRef.MeridianConvex = MeridianConvex;
                ZedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
                PlotRef.zedGraphType = ZedGraphControl1;
                PlotRef.PlotLensProfile();
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException e)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
        }
```

The whole source code was in VB and has been converted to C# using Telerik Online Tool.

I am adding the original method in VB for better understanding

```
Private Sub PlotLensPlanThreadFunction()
        Dim ErrorFlag As ErrorFlagType = InitErrorFlag()
        Dim InMedia As Graphics = Me.PicLensPlot.CreateGraphics
        Dim PlotRef As New PlotLensPlanThread()
        Try
            PlotRef.ThreadInGrphRef = InMedia
            PlotRef.ThreadInConcavePaths = ConcavePaths
            PlotRef.ThreadInConvexPaths = ConvexPaths
            PlotRef.ThreadPlotOptions = PlotOptions.PlanView
            PlotRef.ThreadStepSixData = JobData.StepSixData
            PlotRef.ThreadStepFourData = JobData.StepFourData
            PlotRef.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag
            PlotRef.MeridianConcave = MeridianConcave
            PlotRef.MeridianEdge = MeridianEdge
            PlotRef.MeridianConvex = MeridianConvex
            PlotRef.PlotLensPlan()
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I am getting error in the C# statement 
 **PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread();** The error is 
**PlotLensProfileThread' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'**

Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in the said line `PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread();` cause in your class you already defined a thread instance with the same name as can be seen below

```
Thread PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess(), ....
```

In your method, `PlotLensProfileThread` is it a custom class or something? By any way you should use a different name either for your thread or for your type.

Comment: PlotLensProfileThread is a variable used to create object of the ThreadClass ,please see the code

Comment: @Apoorv, yes seen it and so answered it. Issue is you already have a thread instance defined with that name and trying to use the same name in your method

Comment: How to use  PlotRef? the function uses PlotRef and I know PlotLensProfileThread is a variable. cant create obejct of a variable.

Comment: @Apoorv, can't say unless you tell me what is `PlotLensProfileThread` actually? are you trying to access the thread instance you declare outside method body (OR) is it a custom class defined by you?