# Error Converting VB code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

So I had this old VB code in WinForms which I thought to convert to C# using Telerik Online Converter.

Post conversion , I am facing an issue that is not gettinf resolved.

The VB code is here

```vb
Private Sub PlotLensProfileThreadFunction()
    Dim ErrorFlag As ErrorFlagType = InitErrorFlag()
    Dim InMedia As Graphics = Me.PicLensPlot.CreateGraphics
    Dim PlotRef As New PlotLensProfileThread()
    Try
        PlotRef.ThreadInGrphRef = InMedia
        PlotRef.ThreadInConcavePaths = ConcavePaths
        PlotRef.ThreadInConvexPaths = ConvexPaths
        PlotRef.ThreadPlotOptions = PlotOptions.ProfileView
        PlotRef.ThreadStepSixData = JobData.StepSixData
        PlotRef.ThreadStepFiveData = JobData.StepFiveData
        PlotRef.ThreadStepFourData = JobData.StepFourData
        PlotRef.ThreadStepThreeData = JobData.StepThreeData
        PlotRef.ThreadStepTwoData = JobData.StepTwoData
        PlotRef.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag
        PlotRef.MeridianConcave = MeridianConcave
        PlotRef.MeridianEdge = MeridianEdge
        PlotRef.MeridianConvex = MeridianConvex
        ZedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear()
        PlotRef.zedGraphType = ZedGraphControl1
        PlotRef.PlotLensProfile()
    Catch e As System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
        System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Converted C# code is here

```
private void PlotLensProfileThreadFunction()
{
    Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag =FrontEndStructures. InitErrorFlag();
    Graphics InMedia = this.PicLensPlot.CreateGraphics();



    PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread();
    // var PlotRef = PlotLensProfileThread;
    try
    {
        PlotRef.ThreadInGrphRef = InMedia;
        PlotRef.ThreadInConcavePaths = ConcavePaths;
        PlotRef.ThreadInConvexPaths = ConvexPaths;
        PlotRef.ThreadPlotOptions = PlotOptions.ProfileView;
        PlotRef.ThreadStepSixData = JobData.StepSixData;
        PlotRef.ThreadStepFiveData = JobData.StepFiveData;
        PlotRef.ThreadStepFourData = JobData.StepFourData;
        PlotRef.ThreadStepThreeData = JobData.StepThreeData;
        PlotRef.ThreadStepTwoData = JobData.StepTwoData;
        PlotRef.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag;
        PlotRef.MeridianConcave = MeridianConcave;
        PlotRef.MeridianEdge = MeridianEdge;
        PlotRef.MeridianConvex = MeridianConvex;
        ZedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
        PlotRef.zedGraphType = ZedGraphControl1;
        PlotRef.PlotLensProfile();
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
    }
}
```

The VB class has the definition of some Threads which are being used in the function

```vb
Public Class FrmSoftJobProcess
    Dim PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate As New ThreadStart(AddressOf PlotLensProfileThreadFunction)
    Dim PlotLensProfileThread As New Thread(PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate)
    Dim PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate As New ThreadStart(AddressOf PlotLensPlanThreadFunction)
    Dim PlotLensPlanThread As New Thread(PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate)

    Dim MiniFilename As String

    Dim JobData As SoftJobDataType
    Dim MeridianConvex As Integer
    Dim MeridianConcave As Integer
    Dim MeridianEdge As Integer
    Dim NumberOfTabs As Integer

    Dim ConcavePaths As PSMG.Minifile.MinifileDocument
    Dim ConvexPaths As PSMG.Minifile.MinifileDocument

    Dim DisplayPlot As FrontEndStructures.DisplayPlotType
    Dim PlotOptions As PlotOptionsType

    Dim WithEvents MaterialFrm As FrmAddMaterial
    Dim WithEvents ConcaveToricDesignFrm As frmBCMulticurveToricdesign
    Dim WithEvents ConcaveSphereDesignFrm As frmBCMulticurveSphereDesign
    Dim WithEvents DesignFrm As frmSoftConvexdesign
    Dim WithEvents NewFrm As FrmMarkerDefinition

    Dim WithEvents TabPageChangeTracker As New TrackChanges
```

The converted C# code is

```
public partial class FrmSoftJobProcess : Form
{

    public FrmSoftJobProcess()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += FrmJobProcess_Load;
        FormClosing += FrmJobProcess_FormClosing;
    }

    frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
    ThreadStart PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(new FrmSoftJobProcess(). PlotLensProfileThreadFunction); //This has to be revisited again
    Thread PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess(). PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate);
    ThreadStart PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(new FrmSoftJobProcess().PlotLensPlanThreadFunction);

    Thread PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess().PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);

    string MiniFilename;
    Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.SoftJobDataType JobData;
    int MeridianConvex;
    int MeridianConcave;
    int MeridianEdge;

    int NumberOfTabs;
    PSMG.Minifile.MinifileDocument ConcavePaths;

    PSMG.Minifile.MinifileDocument ConvexPaths;
    FrontEndStructures.DisplayPlotType DisplayPlot;
```

Now the problem is that I am unable to access **PlotLensProfileThread** and **InRef** on this statement   **PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread();** . The compiler throws error **PlotLensProfileThread' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'**

Can anyone help ?

Comment: in VB.net the code is calling a method by the 'AddressOf' which is a pointer to the start location of the function.  It is not the same as PlotLensProfileThread() where the compiler in c# is creating a call to the method.  See webpage : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met

Comment: PlotLensProfileThread is not a function . as fat as I understand , its a variable used in the ThreadStart class to create object   Thread PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess().PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);

Comment: The vb code says : "AddressOf PlotLensProfileThreadFunction"

Comment: See my answer - C# instance fields cannot access other instance members in their initializers.  It's a well-known difference between VB and C# and the converter you used should have taken care of this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike VB, in C#, an instance field cannot reference other instance members in it's declaration's initializer.
You have 4 fields in your class which do exactly this and the work-arounds you have attempted are just digging you deeper into trouble. The usual correct work-around is to call an initializer method from your constructors.
The converted code (just the first 4 fields of your class to pinpoint the problem) is:

```
public class FrmSoftJobProcess
{
    //use a flag to prevent duplicate initialization for the case of chained constructor calls:
    private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;

    public FrmSoftJobProcess()
    {
        if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
        {
            InitializeInstanceFields();
            InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeInstanceFields()
    {
        PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensProfileThreadFunction);
        PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate);
        PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensPlanThreadFunction);
        PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);
    }

    private ThreadStart PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate;
    private Thread PlotLensProfileThread;
    private ThreadStart PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate;
    private Thread PlotLensPlanThread;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. I hope this way It should work for me. I have one more issue , would like to seek in your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095919/error-accessing-threadstart-object-inside-a-function     can you have a look here ?

Comment: @Apoorv: Sorry, but I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: Oh. I thought you would be able to help :( Struck up there . Dont know how to resolve it

Comment: what about these ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114772/c-sharp-equivalent-for-these-vb-statements