# C# equivalent for these VB statements

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am looking for the C# alternatives for these statements which were in VB and have been converted to C# using Telerik online convertor . The compiler gives error as it is unable to identify these statements.

- My.Settings.Reload();
- My.Settings.MainScreenLeft = Me.Left
- My.Settings.MainScreenTop = Me.Top
- My.Settings.MainScreenWidth = Me.Width
- My.Settings.Save()
- My.Settings.Mode = CboMode.SelectedItem.ToString

Comment: My could be this, and Me could be also this, ToString is ToString()

Comment: No @Stanley its not like this. The Settings class itself doesnt exist in C#

Comment: The `Settings` class does actually exist in C#. @Stanley, `Me` is `this` not `My` if that makes sense : ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct translation for `My` in C#. This link gives details on using VB's `My` class in C#:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136.aspx

Since you're trying to access the settings of the project using Settings, try replacing `My.Settings.` in your statements with `Properties.Settings.Default.`. Ensure the properties you're accessing (like `MainScreenTop`) exist as settings in the project's properties.

Comment: thats what I am going to do now. Will post shortlty

Comment: unable to call MySettings.Save()

Comment: You got to use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`. Simply replace `My.Settings.` in your statements with `Properties.Settings.Default.` and ensure you have the following settings in your project (`MainScreenLeft, MainScreenTop, MainScreenWidth, Mode`)

Comment: just figured it out @Ashwin . Ashwin there is a property for CultureInfo in My settings file but I am unable to add System.Globalization as "Type" . any idea

Comment: Use the string parameter to initialize `CultureInfo` as a `Setting` ("en-GB for example") and use it in your code as follows: `var culture  = new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.CultureString)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use setting variables:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i think I just need to do that. Let me check . I think I need to create those variables in the settings file and then se..

Comment: unable to call MySettings.Save()

Comment: To create setting variables go to project properties and then to settings.
To save changed variables you need to call :
Properties.Settings.Default.Save()

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that your converter likely did not correctly convert the original Settings.Designer.vb file.

The original would normally be structured like this:

```
Partial NotInheritable Class Settings
    Inherits Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
    ...
End Class
```

But your C# file should be structured like the following to get the previous suggestions to work:

```
namespace YourRootNamespace //project-level original VB 'root' namespace, if you have one
{
    namespace Properties
    {
        internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now the suggestions about using 'Properties.Settings.Default' will work.

Also, at the bottom of that class, VB includes a module 'MySettingsProperty' in the 'My' namespace - just remove this (this just allowed the 'Settings' class to be included in the 'My' namespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenLeft = this.Left;

Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenTop = this.Top;

Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenWidth = this.Width;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Mode = CboMode.SelectedItem.ToString();
```